# Send model from .Net client to WebApi Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

There are very simple question, but I can't find answer. I have model with multiple field. For example:

```
public class BillingInfoViewModel
{
    //Distributor Information
    public string DistributorName { get; set; }
    public string DistributorEmail { get; set; }
    public string DistibutorPhone { get; set; }
    public CompanyCode CompanyCode { get; set; }

    //ECU information
    public string EcuName { get; set; }
    public string EcuPartNumber { get; set; }
    public string EcuProgramName { get; set; }

   //Lot of fields 
}
```

It is the information which I should  send  to server. How I can do it? Should I send this fields one by one?

```
public void ApiController(string DistributorName, string DistributorEmail, ..othern fields)
```

In what case i can should send all object?

```
public void ApiController(BillingInfoViewModel model)
```

P.S. I send info by System.Net.Http.HttpClient

Comment: From client to server, send this data as JSON. Your JSON property names should be same property names of model class BillingInfoViewModel.

Comment: You can send the entire model by serializing into json object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, the complex parameter type is passed with POST verb. You can use GET verb, but it has url limits in browser and the parameters are visible. Here is a detail guide of parameter bindings which introduces several ways to implement your requirement.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Answer (score 1):

if you're using Asp.NET WebAPI

try this for example:

```
public class BillingController{

public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]BillingInfoViewModel model){
 // HERE YOU GET THE BillingInfoViewModel obj from the call (in POST)
}

}
```

Hope it help